# The election overflows

Tags: bug, design, moderator-election

The election page has a `#mainbar` whose width is 728px.

Inside that there is the `.election-candidates` table, which contains the info about the candidates.

But it's too wide, because the vote buttons are 125px wide and the post texts are 635px. There are also 5px of padding.

```
125px + 635px + 5px = 765px > 728px
```

So there is overflow. It's ugly.

[image]

Comment: Hey, can you vote for Community now :)

Comment: @Glorfindel At first I was going to gray out my votes, but it's less boring like this

Comment: Also, why `.election-candidates` is a table? Tables shouldn't be used for layout.

Comment: @Gothdo All Stack Overflow is full of tables. My guess was that the reason was old IE compatibility. Since only the [last two versions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/195099) are supported, now flexbox could be used instead.

Comment: It also overlaps the footer (if you scroll down to the bottom of the page)

Comment: @Glorfindel community already has a diamond. If she win the election, nothing would change from her perspective.